# This Iron Python Package Do Not Contain Ironpython.module.dll?

Tags: python, ironpython

I am using [IronPython 1.0](http://ironpythonstudio.codeplex.com/releases/view/8934).

This version does not contain *Ironpython.module.dll* and results in an error OS module importing error.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [IronPython 2.7](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/54498). If you need Visual Studio support, you can use [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/).